# How to set font colors of individual words printed to console

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, fonts

I wrote a simple print function that prints out a word letter-by-letter into the console.  I also want to print out text with different colors strictly using Javascript, for example:

```
print("Hello", "green"); print(" World", "blue"); 

function print(word, color) 
    var console = document.getElementById("myConsole");
    console.style.color = color;
    console.append(word);
```

I would like "Hello" to be green and "World" to be blue, but instead what happens is that the console prints out "Hello" in green, but then prints out "World" in blue, while changing the color of "Hello" to blue as well.

I have a more elaborate example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Jsbbvk/vL8tLwfh/

Is there a way to access the individual word's font color?

Comment: So you need to create individual element.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new element, apply the color to it, add that element to your main element, then append the text

```js
function showText(message, color, index, interval, callback) {
  if (index < message.length) {
   var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.color = color;
    document.getElementById("text_target").append(span);
    span.append(message[index++]);
    setTimeout(function() {
      showText(message, color, index, interval, callback);
    }, interval);
  } else {
    callback && callback();
  }
}


showText("HELLO", "green", 0, 200, function() {
  showText(" DONE", "red", 0, 200);
});
//Hello should be green and Done should be red
//how do you set individual text colors?
```

```html
<div id="msg" />
<span id="text_target"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create another element and append the word to it. then append the element to console.

In the below snippet, I changed the variable name console because it already has a meaning in JavaScript

```js
print("Hello", "green");
print(" World", "blue"); 
function print(word, color){
    var conso = document.getElementById("myConsole");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.style.color = color;
    span.append(word);
    conso.append(span);
}
```

```html
<div id="myConsole"></div>
```